# jit-grunt: Plugin for the "clean" task not found

Tags: magento-2.1, grunt

After running `grunt clean` in magento 2.1.3 root folder I get error

```
 If you have installed the plugin already, please setting the static mapping.
See https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt#static-mappings

Warning: Task "clean" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I tried `npm install clean` & `npm install clean --save-dev` but get the same error.  I looked at the url they sent but it is not clear what I should add where?

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
npm install grunt-clean --save-dev
```